# How to add back missing gradle-wrapper.jar to Git repo for Jenkins to do its job

Tags: java, git, jenkins, gradle, gradlew

Whenever my Jenkins job clones my project from GitHub, it is not able to run gradlew command due to missing gradle-wrapper.jar under myproject/gradle/wrapper folder. I have to manually copy paste from another source and re-run the Jenkins job.

Somehow I erroneously had deleted this jar file. The .gitignore file does not detect the newly added jar file either. Due to which I am not able to commit the missing jar to repo. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue.
I am very specific about using gradlew and not gradle
Below is the .gitignore file

```
HELP.md
.gradle
build/
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**/build/
!**/src/test/**/build/

### Gradle ###
.gradle
build/

# Ignore Gradle GUI config
gradle-app.setting

# Avoid ignoring Gradle wrapper jar file (.jar files are usually ignored)
!gradle-wrapper.jar

# Cache of project
.gradletasknamecache

### Gradle Patch ###
**/build/

### Java ###
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log


# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by commenting the *.jar in gitignore file and added the specific gradle-wrapper.jar to repo